# How do I set return value of a mock I created in beforeAll() in a particular test [Jest]

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I solved the problem I presented in [How to mock a constructor in a class I want to test in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900525/how-to-mock-a-constructor-in-a-class-i-want-to-test-in-jest). Still, the solution causes `shuffle()` to return the same array for every test:

```ts
describe('A suite', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('./random', async () => {
      const { Foo } = await import('./Foo');

      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('./random'),
        shuffle: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([new Foo()]),
      };
    });
  });

  test(...);
});
```

But I need to have array of 3 items in one test and of 4 items in the other. Essentially, I need to be able to access the `random.shuffle()` in every test and call `mockReturnValue()` on it. I tried:

```ts
const mockShuffle = shuffle as jest.MockedFunction<typeof shuffle>;

describe('', () => {
... <beforeAll as above>

  test('yyy', () => {
    mockShuffle.mockReturnValue([...]);
  });
});
```

but turns out that `TypeError: mockShuffle.mockReturnValue is not a function`. So, How do I set the returned value per test?

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of mock:

```
const mockShuffle = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([new Foo()]);
jest.mock('./random', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./random'),
  shuffle: () => mockShuffle(),
}));

test('yyy', () => {
  // mock return value of the mock as you like
  mockShuffle.mockReturnValue([...]);
});
```